# Dúvida com a utilização de placeholder e onfocus em HTML

Tags: html, html5

Galera, tô criando uma tela de login onde quero usar `placeholder` e `onfocus` pra quando o user clicar na box desaparecer o que está escrito (por exemplo: "e-mail") e, caso ele apague tudo de novo, a palavra "e-mail" volte a aparecer.

Consegui fazer com o seguinte código

```html
<div class="dados-div" id="dados-senha">
                <input type="password" placeholder="senha" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'senha'" />
            </div>
```

Porém, preciso deixar a palavra sem esse `blur` e não consigo.

### EDIT

Colocando o código inteiro

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Login trevoso</title>
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

        body {
            background-color: #00aba9
        }
        #login-box{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 800px;
            height: 325px;
            position:absolute; /* Aqui começa a rotina que vai até o final do estilo e centraliza a box no meio da tela, conforme Léo of the North pediu. Redimensiona se o user redimensionar o navegador */
            left:50%;
            top:50%;
            margin-left:-400px;
            margin-top:-162.5px;

        }

        #login-box-shadow{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 800px;
            height: 326px;
            margin: auto auto 0px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px grey;
        }

        #login-trevoso {
            background-color: white;
            font: bold 33pt/33px sans-serif;
            color: #00aba9;
            padding: 32px 29px 15px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        .dados-div input{
            width: 750px;
            height: 60px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            font: italic 18pt/10px sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #2e2e2e;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
            outline: none;
        }

        .dados-div {
            margin-left:15px;
            margin-top:15px;
        }

        .dados-div:hover input{
            border-color: #00aba9;
        }

        #botao {
            float:right;
            margin-right: 24px;
            color: white;
            background-color: #00aba9;
            padding: 15px 33px;
            border-radius:3px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #007372;
            font: bold 12,41pt sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            margin-top:19px;
            cursor:pointer;
            transition: background-color 1s;
        }

        #botao:hover {
            background-color: #007372;
        }

        #miss {
            margin-top:15px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            font: normal 13pt sans-serif;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            cursor:pointer;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login-box">
    <div id="login-box-shadow">
        <div id="login-trevoso"> Login  </div>
        <div class="dados-div" id="dados-usuario">
<div class="dados-div" id="dados-senha">
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'e-mail'" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dados-div" id="dados-senha">
            <div class="dados-div" id="dados-senha">
        <input type="password" placeholder="senha" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'senha'" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="botoes">
            <div id="botao">ENVIAR</div>
            <!-- <div id="Lembrar-me"><input type="checkbox"/>Lembrar-me neste computador?</div>-->
        </div>
        <div id="miss"><a href="trouxao.html" style="text-decoration:none">Esqueceu a senha?</a></div>

    </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você já está usando ali o placeholder="Texto no campo"

Comment: @maxixilianoMeyer tente ser mais claro

Comment: Pelo que entendi, ele quer que quando o usuário apagar a senha, que reapareça o placeholder... inclui o snippet pra facilitar o entendimento, mas ainda não aprovaram a edição... não sei se dá pra fazer só com HTML... @AndréBaill

Comment: Mas @gustavox o próprio placeholder faz isso

Comment: Isso, @Gustavox. Que reapareça o placeholder, mas sem o blur

Comment: @AndréBaill olha o snippet (Executrar trecho de código)... Quando vc apaga a senha ele não volta o texto do placeholder...

Comment: Postei uma resposta com a simulação, ao meu ver, seria isso

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer quando você diz: "sem esse `blur`" você quer dizer a cor da fonte? Tirar a cor cinza e colocar preta no placeholder?

Comment: Isso@Gerep Além disso o blur tá mudando a formatação que eu fiz, deixando a fonte maior, por exemplo, cortando a parte de cima da palavra que fica muito grande pra caixa

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, você pode atualizar o exemplo mostrando esse problema com a fonte?

Comment: Coloquei pra ti um exemplo, talvez seria essa sua idéia?

Comment: @Gerep Coloquei o código inteiro

Comment: @AndréBaill vou testar

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer o seu problema com a fonte esta nesta linha `font: italic 18px/10px sans-serif;` porque você esta fazendo desse modo?

Comment: @Gerep faz parte das "intruções" da tarefa. A fonte precisa ser em itálico e ter esse tamanho. Obrigado pelo toque, reparei que tinha coisa a mais ali mesmo, tirei o 10px e ficou de boas, não corta mais o texto

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, na minha resposta eu expliquei um pouco melhor o que acontece nessa linha.

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, para ajudar a comunidade, escolha a resposta que te ajudou.

Comment: @Gerep Não havia marcado nenhum, pois para mim eles não funcionaram direitinho. Bem, marcarei a melhor resposta, pois mesmo assim poderá ajudar os demais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada navegador tem sua implementação (pseudo-element/class) do `placeholder`.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {   /* WebKit browsers */
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="dados-div" id="dados-senha">
    <input type="password" placeholder="senha" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onkeyup="this.placeholder = 'senha'" />
</div>
```

Fonte: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Em relação a fonte não estar centralizada no `input`:

```
font: italic 18px/10px sans-serif;
```

Você esta definindo o tamanho da fonte e também a propriedade `line-height`. O problema não é definir os dois juntos, o problema esta nos valores.

Comment: Resolveu o problema do placeholder, mas ainda não deu certo no onfocus (não apagou o que estava na tela para o usuário clicou na box)

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, não entendi o problema com `onfocus()`, quando você clica no campo novamente ele deveria apagar o que o usuário digitou?!

Comment: Não. Funciona assim. Na caixa está escrito "e-mail". Com o onfocus quando o usuário clicar na caixa a palavra "e-mail" desaparecem, na verdade ela é substituída por nada, mais exatamente por " " que está setado em onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, quando eu clico no campo, ele remove o que esta no `value` e colocar o seu `""`, o que mais você precisa que faça? É isso que não estou entendendo. Para você o "email" ou "senha" não esta sendo removido quando você clica no campo?

Comment: @Gerep, precisa que quando apagar o que foi digitado, que reapareça o placeholder.

Comment: @Gerep exatamente. Mas no exemplo que você me passou isso não está acontecendo. Está dando certo aí para você?

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, o placeholder volta quando você tira o foco do campo. Eu digitei um e-mail, apaguei o valor, tirei o foco do campo e o `placeholder` voltou a aparecer

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, sim, aqui esta funcionando perfeitamente

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer https://jsfiddle.net/ug5L491t/, dê uma olhada por favor e veja se esta funcionando.

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer aqui também tá funcionando, mas só volta o `placeholder` quando perde o foco, e acho que vc precisa como com `onkeyup` né...

Comment: @Gerep fiz um teste aqui, acho que se mudar seu fiddle pra `onkeyup="this.placeholder = 'e-mail'"` fica 100% o que AP precisa (btw, que navegador vc tá usando AP?)...

Comment: @gustavox, muito obrigado pela dica, já esta atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/ug5L491t/1/

Comment: Lembra de arrumar também na resposta (no snippet). Dei +1 na sua resposta, e acho que solucionou né @MaximilianoMeyer? Se tiver solucionado, não esqueça de dar um voto positivo e marcar a resposta como aceita.

Comment: @gustavox, atualizado também =)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda galera. Abração. Vou dar o +1 sim

Comment: Vou aceitar sim, é que tô testando aqui ainda uheuheh.

Comment: Abração @gustavox e muito obrigado pela ajuda. Quem sbe um dia eu consiga te retribuir

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o mesmo placeholder para elaborar isto, ao você digitar ele some, quando você remover a escrita, retorna o placeholder. Segue o exemplo.

Neste meu exemplo, você poderá trocar a cor também da escrita, creio que deva lhe ajudar.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: orange;
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
   color: orange;
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
   color: orange;  
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: orange;  
   font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha"/>
```

Comment: Obrigado André, mas nesse caso ele não apagou o o placeholder quando  clico no campo de inserção.

Comment: Resolveu o problema do placeholder, mas ainda não deu certo no onfocus (não apagou o que estava na tela para o usuário clicou na box)

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer fiz um teste aqui com este código incluindo `onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"` e ele some quando clica em cima, mas não reaparece quando apaga tudo...